# I want the loop running until numbers are: 123

Tags: c++, random, while-loop, numbers, do-while

I have 2 different codes that to me look the same, but they aren't. The first one works as I want, the second doesn't. I don't understand why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3, i=0;
    srand(time(0));
    do{
    i++;
    num1=rand()%3+1;
    num2=rand()%3+1;
    num3=rand()%3+1;
    cout<<i<<"."<<num1<<num2<<num3<<endl;
    }while(!((num1==1)&&(num2==2)&&(num3==3)));

}
```

This is the second one. As I understand it, do-while loop should run until num1 doesn't equal to 1, num2 doesn't equal to 2 and num3 doesn't equal to 3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3, i=0;
    srand(time(0));
    do{
    i++;
    num1=rand()%3+1;
    num2=rand()%3+1;
    num3=rand()%3+1;
    cout<<i<<"."<<num1<<num2<<num3<<endl;
    }while((num1!=1)&&(num2!=2)&&(num3!=3));

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:
`while(((num1==1)&&(num2==2)&&(num3==3)));`
do while loop will end when all of these three are different from the values you have printed. Also I highly suggest on learning bool arithmetic, especially [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

!(A && B) = !A || !B !(A || B) = !A && !B so

```
!((num1==1)&&(num2==2)&&(num3==3))
```

will convert into

```
(!(num1==1)||!(num2==2)||!(num3==3))
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two codes is that the first code will iterate until all three variables meet their respective conditions, but the second code will continue until *at least one* of the variables meets its condition. That's how it comes out when evaluating using boolean logic. If you wanted to correct the second condition without using the beginning !, you could change the condition to:

```
while((num1 != 1) || (num2 != 2) || (num3 != 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the do-while statement in the first program

```
while(!((num1==1)&&(num2==2)&&(num3==3)));
```

can be equivalently converted to

```
while( (num1!=1) || (num2!=2) || (num3 != 3)));
```

that means that at least one of the variables is not equal to 1 or 2 or 3.

The condition in the do-while statement in the second program

```
}while((num1!=1)&&(num2!=2)&&(num3!=3));
```

means that num1 is not equal to 1 and num2 is not equal to 2 and num3 is not equal to 3.

It is obvious that the conditions

```
while( (num1!=1) or (num2!=2) or (num3 != 3)));
```

and

```
}while( (num1!=1) and (num2!=2) and (num3!=3));
```

are different.

Thus the programs behave differently.:)